# Simple dropdown does not work in mobile mode

Tags: css, dropdown

I am trying to implement a simple dropdown element just like that described in the [W3C example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test-dropdown-01.css">
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span>Mouse over me!!</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    Hello Mouse!!
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown
{
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content
{
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content
{
  display: block;
}
```

It functions as expected when I test it in desktop mode, but when I switch into a phone mode (on Firefox, via Ctrl+Shift+M), there is no dropdown any longer. What is that I did not take into account?

Comment: _"What is that I did not take into account?"_ - that `:hover` will of course be problematic on touchscreen devices.

Comment: @CBroe I see. What would be an alternative? And: the effect I mention was not on touchscreen, but with a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

On phone mode there is no hover effect not even in chrome inspector with mouse

In the mobile view, you can simulate touch events like tapping and scrolling, but hover events triggered by a mouse cursor hovering over an element will not be triggered.

Comment: Thanks Telexx. Strangely I failed to find this simple explanation anywhere. Is there an option to have a simple dropdown with CSS only that would function in mobile mode? (To be concrete, I mean "@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {...}")
Is it still possible with pure CSS or is JS the only option?

Comment: I don't think its possible with only CSS, you need JS to handle the click event

Comment: I was afraid, so. Thanks.